# Replace resources with CDN path using grunt

Tags: regex, angularjs, amazon-s3, gruntjs

I am using yeoman's `generator-angular-fullstack`. It's grunt build task will minify, concat and create revved files.

Now I want to improve it a little more , that I am planning to upload these revved files to s3 and replace the urls in my index.html.

path in finished html files are

`<script src="app/9083921.app.js"></script>`

I want to replace them with

`<script src="http://cdn/9083921.app.js"></script>`

I got `grunt-aws-s3` for uploading files to s3 it is wroking.

now for replacing it in index.html file

I tried `grunt-replace`, `grunt-text-replace`, `grunt-regex-replace`, none of the seems to work in my case. I tried with regex as `/app\/(.*)\.(js|css)/g` with   `http://path/$1.$2`. didn't work

`grunt-processhtml` already included in the generator which helps to get all the files in a folder. like this

`<!-- build:css(client) app/app.css -->`

So I am unable to use `grunt-processhtml` to do rewrite the path

is there any task to do this or what am i doing wrong.

**EDIT** my cdnify task

```
cdnify: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          base: '//cdn.com/'
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'dist',
          src: 'public/app/index.html',
          dest: 'dist'
        }]
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [grunt-cdnify](https://github.com/callumlocke/grunt-cdnify)? It should pretty much cover you:

> Grunt plugin for rewriting static resource URLs found in your HTML and CSS.
>
> ### What it does
>
> The task looks through your specified files for URLs to rewrite, in the following places:
>
> `<img src="____">`
>
> `<script src="____"></script>`
>
> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="____">`
>
> `background-image: url(____);` in your CSS (including inside  tags in your HTML)

The basic task is pretty straightforward too:

```
cdnify: {
  someTarget: {
    options: {
      base: '//cdn.example.com/stuff/'
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'app',
      src: '**/*.{css,html}',
      dest: 'dist'
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but I am getting the following error : 

Running "cdnify:dev" (cdnify) task
Verifying property cdnify.dev exists in config...OK
Warning: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: Added cdnify in the question.

Comment: @Sreevisakh I think that the src-attribute should be an array: `src: ['public/app/index.html']`

Comment: Yes, thanks, I debugged cdnify task and found out that :) It is working now. and I had grunt-google-cdn also which have the same task name.